# How to add CSS file to qweb report in Odoo 10?

Tags: css, report, odoo, qweb

i want to add custom css file to qweb report template. I tried to add like below but it didn't work :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report id="my_module.report_id" model="my_module.report_model" string="Some Model Report" report_type="qweb-pdf" name="my_module.report_name" file="my_module.report_name_file" menu="False"/>
        <template id="my_module_inherit_id" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel='stylesheet' href="/my_module/static/src/css/report_style.css"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
        <template id="my_module.report_name">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                        <style>
                        .test_class{color:blue;}
                        </style>
                        <!-- <div class="header">
                        </div> -->

                        <div class="body">
                            <h1 class="test_class" t-esc="test_variable['subVariable']"/>
                            <h1 class="test_class2" t-esc="test_variable['subVariable']"/>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

defined style in page classed div is working well. But i want to add css file too. I tried below inherit ids as well but none of them worked :

```
report.minimal_layout
report.internal_layout
report.assets_common
web.assets_backend
report.style
report.external_layout
```

css file :

```
.test_class2{
    color: red;
}
```

css file path:

```
/my_module/static/src/css/report_style.css
```

Comment: What about `<h1 style="color: red;" t-esc="test_variable['subVariable']"/>`. It's work in `ir.ui.view` for form view

Comment: Yes, using style in qweb works but my css file is just an example, i want to add css files in qweb report.

Comment: Have you add `'css': ['static/src/css/report_style.css',],` in `__manifest__.py` ?

Comment: Yes, i add it and tried again but still same (and i defined css line before defining report_template.xml in manifest file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue :

```
<template id="report_style_inherit" inherit_id="report.internal_layout">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">

                <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8069/module_name/static/src/css/libs/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            </xpath>
        </template>
```

using "report.internal_layout" as an inherit_id and adding odoo server link to css path solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to put tag template in tag report :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
<template id="my_module_inherit_id" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel='stylesheet' href="/my_module/static/src/css/report_style.css"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
        <report id="my_module.report_id" model="my_module.report_model" string="Some Model Report" report_type="qweb-pdf" name="my_module.report_name" file="my_module.report_name_file" menu="False"/>
        <template id="my_module.report_name">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                        <style>
                        .test_class{color:blue;}
                        </style>
                        <!-- <div class="header">
                        </div> -->

                        <div class="body">
                            <h1 class="test_class" t-esc="test_variable['subVariable']"/>
                            <h1 class="test_class2" t-esc="test_variable['subVariable']"/>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

According to the following steps: 
https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/apply-css-from-external-file-in-odoo-qweb-reports

Thanks

Comment: report tag is closed, it doesn't have any template tag inside. if you mean defining css file before report i also tried that but nothing changed